# Get output of intermediate layers in keras throws name error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, layer

I want to visualize the layers in capsule networks. For that I need shape of intermediate layers. The code is as follows:

```
from keras.models import Model
model = Sequential()
conv1 = model.add(Conv2D(256, (9, 9), padding='valid', strides = 1, input_shape = (28, 28, 1), activation = 'relu', name = 'conv1'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (9,9), padding='valid', strides = 2, name = 'primarycaps_conv2d'))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Reshape([-1,8]))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Lambda(squash, name = 'hello'))

layer_name = 'conv1'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                             outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(data)
```

Throws the following error:

```
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800025/keras-give-input-to-intermediate-layer-and-get-final-output), I got the solution as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
conv1 = model.add(Conv2D(256, (9, 9), padding='valid', strides = 1, input_shape = (28, 28, 1), activation = 'relu', name = 'conv1'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (9,9), padding='valid', strides = 2, name = 'primarycaps_conv2d'))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Reshape([-1,8]))
model.add(keras.layers.core.Lambda(squash, name = 'hello'))

idx = 3  # index of desired layer
input_shape = model.layers[idx].get_output_shape_at(0)
print(input_shape)
```

get the output shape as follows:

```
(None, 1152, 8).
```

The problem of getting specific layer's output is solved.